# Where are Google Chrome cookies stored on a Mac?

Tags: macos, cookies

Where are Google Chrome cookies located on a mac?

I went
`~/Library/Application Support/Google/Chrome/Default/Cookies`, but I don't think that this file is the one. I cleared cookies, went to this file, copied content, brows a little, paste the content i copied back into the file and saved. I was still logged in gmail.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Session cookies are only stored in memory, but the rest are in `~/Library/Application Support/Google/Chrome/Default/Cookies`, it's an sqlite3 database.

Comment: I deleted the content of file. I am still logged in to http://apple.stackexchange.com/. Looks like sessions cookies is what I need. Perhaps a better question is, how does google chrome delete cookies eg where are session cookies stored?

Comment: "Session cookies are only stored in memory" - If Chrome works the same as on Windows then if it's configured to "continue where you left off" (ie. remember tabs from last time), then Chrome also "remembers" session cookies.

Comment: Okay. Perhaps a better question is, what do you delete when you go to history->delete cookies.

Comment: has this changed? cannot find this location anymore.

Comment: On MacOS High Sierra (and probably other recent OS's) the path is slightly different: `~/Library/ApplicationSupport/Google/Chrome/Default` (ie, remove the space).

Answer (score 1):

It may also depend on whether or not the user is logged into Chrome.  I have cookies located at `~/Library/Application\ Support/Google/Chrome/Profile\ 10/Cookies`.