# 2019 Update: Where does Chrome store cookies on Mac?

Tags: macos, google-chrome, cookies

Apparently the location noted in: [Where are Google Chrome cookies stored on a Mac?](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/232433/where-are-google-chrome-cookies-stored-on-a-mac) is outdated.

This tree no longer exists: `~/Library/Application Support/Google/Chrome/Default/Cookies`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After some searching, I located them here:

```
~/Library/Application Support/Google/Chrome/Profile 1/Cookies
```

and, to view the contents concisely, DB Browser for SQL Lite still works. Just load the cookies file into it.